# Conda: how to avoid hard links

Tags: anaconda, conda

I'm trying to clone a conda environment from an existing one:

```
conda create --copy -n env2 --clone env1
```

When done, I can see that env2 contains hard links to env1's file, even though the `--copy` flag should avoid that happening.

Does anyone know how to clone a conda environment **copying** all files?

Comment: Same question was posted as an issue here: https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/2091